# Cannot use instance member '' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, swiftui

Can someone please help me with this?

'Cannot use instance member '' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available'

```
class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var userInfo = UserModel(uid: "", username: "", pic: "", bio: "")

let ref = Firestore.firestore()
var uid: String

init(uid: String) {
    self.uid = uid
    
    fetchUser(uid: uid) { (user) in
        self.userInfo = user
    }
}
```

[struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oUF6.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The compiler is confused as to which of the two `uids` to use. You want to use the local one. Try retyping it and make sure you choose `local` or, you can always make the init header something like `init(uid initUID: String)` to prevent any confusion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

As the warning says, you cannot use the instance member within the initializer because it is run before 'self' is available.

In this case, `self.userInfo` is the instance member which you are using in the property initializer, `init(uid: String)`, inside that call to `fetchUser(uid: String)`.

Basically, you are trying to use your ProfileViewModel class before it is ready.